# Retrieving depthBuffer of a render for another render pass. (D3DX9)

Tags: directx, direct3d, depth, d3dx

I am rendering a scene to a texture, then using that texture and its depthBuffer in subsequent renderings to apply some effects (Depth Of Field, Bloom, etc...).

Here is the problem: I manage to set the DepthStencilBuffer to a custom surface and render my scene to a texture. The scene is rendered perfectly, and there is no depth problems. This being said, when using the texture (to which the custom surface is bound), all depth values are exactly 1.0

I have suspected the call to device->clear to affect the wrong surface, but even when disabling them, it doesn't fix anything.

Here is the actual code :

```
HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

VCND3D* renderer = static_cast<VCND3D*>( VCNRenderCore::GetInstance() );
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device = renderer->GetD3DDevice();

//device->EndScene();

VCNDXShaderCore* shaderCore = static_cast<VCNDXShaderCore*>( VCNDXShaderCore::GetInstance() );

VCNNode* rootNode = VCNNodeCore::GetInstance()->GetRootNode();

LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 currentSurface;
device->GetRenderTarget(0, &currentSurface);

LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 currentDepthBuffer;
device->GetDepthStencilSurface( &currentDepthBuffer );

///// INITIAL HDR RENDER : //////////////////////////////////////

hr = device->SetRenderTarget( 0, mInitialHDRSurface );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

hr = device->SetDepthStencilSurface( mDepthSurface );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

device->Clear(  0,
                NULL,
                D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
                D3DCOLOR_XRGB(100,100,100),
                1.0f,
                0 );

//device->BeginScene();
rootNode->Render();
//device->EndScene();

//hr = device->UpdateSurface( currentDepthBuffer, NULL, mDepthSurface, NULL );
//VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

//////////// DOF EFFECT : /////////////////////////////////////////////////

hr = device->SetRenderTarget( 0, currentSurface );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_COLORWRITEENABLE, 
D3DCOLORWRITEENABLE_ALPHA | D3DCOLORWRITEENABLE_RED | D3DCOLORWRITEENABLE_GREEN | D3DCOLORWRITEENABLE_BLUE);

device->Clear(  0,
                NULL,
                D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
                D3DCOLOR_XRGB(100,100,100),
                1.0f,
                0 );

//device->BeginScene();

// Set DOF shader
VCNDXShader* dofShader = shaderCore->GetShader( sidDof );

// Field of view to cover full screen :
hr = device->SetFVF(D3DFVF_SCREEN);
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

// select the vertex buffer to display
hr = device->SetStreamSource(0, mScreenVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(SCREENVERTEX));
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

// Draw the Dof result
hr = dofShader->GetEffect()->SetTechnique( "BaseTechnique" );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
hr = dofShader->GetEffect()->SetTexture( "gInputImageTexture", mInitialHDRTexture );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
hr = dofShader->GetEffect()->SetTexture( "gDepthTexture", mDepthTexture );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
hr = dofShader->GetEffect()->SetFloat( "gMinDepth", 3.0f );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
hr = dofShader->GetEffect()->SetFloat( "gMaxDepth", 7.0f );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

dofShader->RenderPrimitive( 2, D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP );

hr = device->SetDepthStencilSurface( currentDepthBuffer );
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
```

And here are the init of the texture and surfaces, because the error could be there :

```
// Texture for the initial HDR Render (Before effects)
hr = device->CreateTexture(res.x, res.y, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &mInitialHDRTexture, 0);
VCN_ASSERT_MSG( SUCCEEDED(hr), _T("Unable to create initial HDR Render Texture") );

// Extract the associated surface for rendering
hr = mInitialHDRTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &mInitialHDRSurface);
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

// Texture with depth of the scene
hr = device->CreateTexture(res.x, res.y, 1, D3DUSAGE_DEPTHSTENCIL, D3DFMT_D32F_LOCKABLE, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &mDepthTexture, 0);
VCN_ASSERT_MSG( SUCCEEDED(hr), _T("Unable to create depth texture") );

// Extract the associated surface for rendering
hr = mDepthTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &mDepthSurface);
VCN_ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
```

Note that no ASSERT is getting triggered (which is exactly what is pissing me off, I would like some errors as an indication of where to look)

Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly you clear `mDepthSurface` twice: first in `INITIAL HDR RENDER` section, then in `DOF EFFECT`. You either need to do a `SetDepthStencilSurface` before second clear, or not setting `D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER` in that call. Otherwise second clear discards whatever is rendered by `rootNode->Render()` and at effect start you have all clear z-buffer.

Comment: Yep, but i discovered before dx10, the depth buffer readback is not officially supported, since the depthStencilBuffer's memory format is free of implementation to the graphic card manufacturer. Seems like it's better to just do a render pass with a shader that prints depth in a R32F texture.